# Summarise with an external variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, summarize

I'm trying to make this code work for an external variable:

```
#This is the original code

library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
nFinal <- 5
graphData <- tibble(y = rep(1:nFinal,2),
                    ponde = runif(10, min = 0, max = 1),
                    )

totalData <- graphData %>%
  **summarise**(val1 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[1]*100,
            val2 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[2]*100,
            val3 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[3]*100,
            val4 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[4]*100,
            val5 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[5]*100)
```

What I would like is for this to be able to be done for a supplied number of values, so the last `val` should depend on a number supplied in an external integer `nFinal` , something like this:

```
nFinal <- 10 #or any value

totalData <- graphData %>%
  summarise(val1 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[1]*100,
            val2 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[2]*100,
            val3 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[3]*100,
            val4 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[4]*100,
            val5 = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[5]*100,
            ... 
          valnFinal = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))[nFinal]*100)
```

I'm using `dplyr` for this but I would accept any other solution.

(edit, made example data have nFinal elements, as pointed out in comment to arkun.)

Comment: Based on your data, the output will be only 5 elements as your number of rows of input is 5

Comment: Also, not sure why you are doing the repeat, instead `graphData %>% summarise(out = prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde))) %>% filter(row_number() <= nFinal)` and then you may reshape to 'wide'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may save the output in a list and use `unnest_wider` to create new columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

graphData %>%
  summarise(val = list(prop.table(questionr::wtd.table(y, weights = ponde)) * 100)) %>%
  unnest_wider(val)

#   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  37.2  20.0  21.8  12.2  8.92
```

Comment: I think this should work! I will try it out and accept in a bit! Thank you!!

Comment: It works exactly how I needed it to work! Thank you! 

I need to use lists more frequently....